# Unable to create a list that is able to dinstinguish between integer and float based on user input

Tags: python, list

The code is supposed to create a list of five list's, with each list created from the numbers the user input each time (of five). So e.g. if user key in

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 2

1.5 2

2.2

1
```

The output should be : `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [1.5, 2], [2,2], [1]]`
Any help is appreciated. I understand that to solve this problem, you need to convert the string into a int or float, but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
nlist = []
n = len(nlist)

while n < 5:
    num = input("Enter a Number: ").split()

    for x in num:

        if '.' in num[x]:
            num[x] = float(num[x])
        else:
            num[x] = int(num[x])

    nlist.append(num)    
    n = n + 1
print(nlist)
```

Comment: `[2,2]` should probably be `[2.2]` in the required output I think

Comment: The line starting your loop `for x in num:` is good but you don't seem to understand that that does, ie, what `x` contains each time around the loop.  I suggest that you put this line immediately after the loop statement `print("x='%s'" % x)` and then think about what you see.  That should get you thinking "why did I put num\[x\] in there?".

Answer (score 1):

Basically in your code you try to acces the `x`th element of list `num` within your `for in` loop, however `x` is not the index of an element inside the list but a reference to it.

Take a look at the modified code:

```
nlist = []
n = len(nlist)

while n < 5:
    num = input("Enter a Number: ").split()

    tmplist = []
    for x in num:

        if '.' in x:
            x = float(x)
        else:
            x = int(x)

        tmplist.append(x)

    nlist.append(tmplist)    
    n = n + 1
print(nlist)
```

So for the following input:

```
Enter a Number: 1 2 3 4 5
Enter a Number: 1 2
Enter a Number: 1.5 2
Enter a Number: 2.2
Enter a Number: 1
```

It will output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [1.5, 2], [2.2], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This method accomplishes the effect you are after, and in much fewer lines:

```
nList = []

for n in range(5):
    #Takes an input "5 3.5 5 2 3" converts it to [5, 3.5, 5, 2, 3]
    listItems = list(map(eval, input("Numbers for sub-list: ").split()))

    #Append the list to the nList
    nList.append(listItems)

print(nList)
```

So instead of nesting two loops, in the '*listItem*' variable it simply takes the input as a string:

```
"5 3.5 2"
```

Splits it:

```
input().split()

["5", "3.5", "2"]
```

Then maps each item to 'eval' which chooses float or integer depending on the string:

```
list(map(eval, input().split()))

[5, 3.5, 2]
```

**Important note:** 'eval' can be a dangerous command to use, be sure to look up the documentation on it extensively before using it further. Check the comments below for more details.

**Alternatively**
If you'd rather not use eval, consider this solution:

```
nList = []

for n in range(5):
    itemList = input("Numbers to add: ").split()
    subList = []

    for item in itemList:


        if "." in item:
            item = float(item)
        else:
            item = int(item)

        subList.append(item)

    nList.append(subList)

print(nList)
```

Comment: `eval` should not be considered in the solution for a problem like this in my opinion.

Comment: If you would rather not use eval simply convert them all to floats instead, as long as it is not integral to the program that some are integers, and some are floats, it would have no effect on performance to make them all floats.

Comment: It's not about performance, but security. `eval` with an untrusted input?

Comment: I've added an alternate solution which doesn't use 'eval', but could you explain the problem with using it? There is no error checking in the program whatsoever, neither in any of the answers provided by anyone, it's not made to be secure, just a simple script to get a job done - if it crashes from an incorrect input, relaunch it

Comment: With the `eval` approach the user can call methods that are in the scope of the module, go and create a function before the for loop like: `def infinite(): while True: pass` then execute a script and type: `Numbers for sub-list: infinite()`. You got an infinite loop from a user input, and of course it's just a silly example, but imagine a function that prints out sensitive data, and the user can easily get it by exploiting `eval`.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but from what I can gather, this is not meant to be a 'secure' program, its a simple script to solve a simple problem. If we wanted to make it as secure as we could then we would but lots of error catching inside, and would not use eval - however the question doesn't require that.

Comment: Of coures that's obvious that all of the solutions introduced here are far from being complete, but there is a difference between showing a simple use case of a `for in` loop and introducing a dangerous and generally bad idea to the OP, right?

Comment: Point taken - I've added a note inside the answer about the dangers of 'eval'

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension` with `str.find` to see whether to convert to `float` or `int`:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for i in range(n): 
        inp = input().split() 
        out.append([ float(ele) if ele.find('.')>-1 else int(ele) for ele in inp])
```

#driver values :

```
IN : n = 5
IN : 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2
1.5 2
2.2
1

OUT : [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [1.5, 2], [2.2], [1]]
```